# What is the rate of convergence of $f^N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^N f_n e^{in x}$ to $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_n e^{in x}$ in $L^2([0,2\pi])$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, approximation

Let $f \in L^2([0,2\pi])$ if $2$$\pi$ periodic. Then $f$ can be decomposed using a Fourier series as
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_n e^{in x}.
$$

Now suppose we approximate $f$ by $f^N$ where $f^N$ is given by
$$
f^N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^N f_n e^{in x}.
$$
I am wondering what the rate of convergence is of this approximation in $L^2([0,2\pi])$? I assume it should be exponential (spectral) as it is based on a Fourier series. I.e.

$$
\begin{align}
||f - f^N||_{L^2([0,2\pi])}^2 & = \int_0^{2\pi} |f - f^N|^2 dx \\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} |\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_n e^{in x} - \sum_{n=-N}^N f_n e^{in x}|^2 dx \\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} |\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_n e^{in x} - \sum_{n=-N}^N f_n e^{in x}|^2 dx \\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} |\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-N-1} f_n e^{in x} + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} f_n e^{in x}|^2 dx \\
& \le \int_0^{2\pi} \left(|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-N-1} f_n e^{in x}| + |\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} f_n e^{in x}|\right)^2 dx \\
& \le \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-N-1} |f_n| + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} |f_n|\right)^2 dx \\
& \le C \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-N-1} |f_n| + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} |f_n|\right)^2 \\
\end{align}
$$
But this doesn't seem to be leading anywhere..I want to end up with something like $$||f - f^N||_{L^2([0,2\pi])}^2 = Ce^{-N}.
$$
I don't have much experience with rate of convergence so what is the actual rate of convergence for this approximation and what is the technique used to obtain it?

Comment: Btw, if you're dealing with $L^2$ norms of Fourier series it should be obvious you should be using Parseval! Those inequalities you have are entirely useless, because it may be that $\sum|f_n|=\infty$, in which case you're just getting $||f-f^N||\le\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that can be said about the rate of convergence without further assumptions on $f$; in fact $||f-f^N||$ can tend to $0$ arbitrarily slowly.

Roughly speaking, a faster rate of convergence implies some sort of smoothness for $f$. For example, If $||f-f^N||\to0$ exponentially then $f_n\to0$ exponentially, which implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

**Edit:** Someone supplied a reference for the "arbitrarily slowly" statement. This is much more trivial than that:

> > **Prop** If $s_0,s_1,s_2,\dots$ is a sequence decreasing to zero then there exists $f\in L^2$ with $||f-f^N||^2=s_N$.

Proof. Let $a_n^2=s_{n-1}-s_n$, and define $f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne^{int}$. Then $$||f-f^N||_2^2=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n^2=s_N.$$

Comment: Regarding the "arbitrarily slowly" comment, I think that en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethargy_theorem is a good reference

Comment: @charMD I guess -- the current "arbitrarily slowly" is completely trivial.

Comment: You are right indeed

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Regarding assumptions on $f$, the $f$ I'm interested in is a smooth function. So how can that assumption be used to show that it converges exponentially in $L^2([0,1])$?

Comment: @eurocoder If smooth means infinitely differentiable that does not imply that the partial sums converge exponentially.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So how do we find the rate of convergence? This approximation could be used in numerical analysis for approximating the function $f$ using a Fourier series basis on $L^2([0,2\pi[)$, and in numerical analysis one of the primary goals is to find the rate/order of convergence? Intuitively this seems to be a highly optimal way to approximate the function so I would definitely expect it to converge exponentially.

Comment: At such a general level it's hard  to say. You figure out what you can about the size of the coefficients $f_n$ and then use Parseval to see what that says about $||f-f^N||$. Yes, $f_N$ gives the best approximation in the $L^2$ norm - why you say this means you'd expect exponential convergence is beyond me.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I expect exponential convergence because this would be a spectral approximation and when I see such approximations mentioned I often see 'exponential convergence' or 'spectral convergence' - even the Wikipedia page for spectral methods methods mentions 'exponential convergence'. Unfortunately every time I see such methods it is just stated that they possess this convergence, I would like to actually see a proof of it.

Comment: When  they "mention" exponential convergence they're talking about the convergence of _what_, precisely?